# Peewee - Determining meta data about Model at run time

Tags: python, peewee

```
class Foo(Model):
    bar = CharField()
    baz = CharField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

<body>
    Create a new Foo:
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <input type="text" name="baz" />
</body>
```

Instead of hard coding the input fields in the html, I would like to be able to determine at run time the names, data types, and other meta data about the fields in a model, and pass them to the html template to loop over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `Model._meta.fields`:

```
In [1]: from peewee import *

In [2]: class User(Model):
   ...:     username = CharField()
   ...:     

In [3]: User._meta.fields
Out[3]: 
{'id': <peewee.PrimaryKeyField at 0x2eba290>,
 'username': <peewee.CharField at 0x2eb4e10>}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [v for k,v in vars(Foo).items() if isinstance(v, peewee.FieldDescriptor)]
>>> for i in x:
...     print(i.att_name, i.field)
...
('bar', <peewee.CharField object at 0x022AC810>)
('baz', <peewee.CharField object at 0x022AC6B0>)
('id', <peewee.PrimaryKeyField object at 0x022B4CD0>)
```

This leverages the Python builtin [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#vars) generate a list of `FieldDescriptor` objects that class `Foo` holds. Note that we are operating on the `Foo` type object directly, obtaining this information from *class* variables.

Once we have all the fields, we can loop over them and examine the column name and type. Most likely, you'll want some kind of `isinstance` check on `field` to figure out type to use in your HTML. I imagine you'll want to filter out or ignore the `PrimaryKeyField`, but I think you can figure that out.

I would caution against doing this, though. It would probably be better to simply maintain the list of fields in your HTML. Yes, it's a little bit of a hassle, but automatically having new columns appear in the HTML page is not necessarily a good thing.

Comment: @coleifer While I respect your opinion as the apparent author of the tool, I'm not quite sure what's here that makes this answer "wrong". In what way could it fail? Additionally, the non-code sections of the answer are applicable to your answer as well. Generally speaking, I appreciate any suggestions for improvement when I get downvoted.

Comment: While this approach works, there is a better way. Peewee has an API (and namespace) for introspecting metadata, Model._meta, which should be used by developers.